# Barra de desplazamiento vertical innecesario

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Voy iniciando en el mundo de desarrollo y me encuentro en el punto de dar estilos a mi página web, el problema es que en mi pagina me sale una barra de desplazamiento como si hubiera mas información que mostrar, he estado buscando y recomiendan como tal ocultar `ek scroll`, pero al mismo tiempo según opiniones es buscar qué elemento hace el scroll, lo he estado buscando pero realmente no he podido conseguirlo, adjunto capturas de lo que menciono.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background-color: #19223e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

/*Main Principal*/

.crear{
    display: flex;

}

/*Paquete Basico*/
.basico{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*Paquete Estandar*/

.estandar{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*Paquete Premiun*/
.premium{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inscripcion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!--Cuerpo pricipal-->
    <main class="crear">
        
        <!--Paquete Básico-->
        <section class="basico">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>BASIC</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">100GB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $1,7/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>
            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>100 GB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Paquete Estandar-->
        <section class="estandar">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>STANDARD</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">200GB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $2,9/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>

            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>200 GB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Paquete Premiun-->
        <section class="premium">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>PREMIUM</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">2TB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $8,9/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>

            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>2 TB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Adjunto el código que he realizado para algunas observaciones, gracias.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que algunos navegadores agregan estilos a los elementos por defecto.

En este link [CSS Default Values Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) puedes encontrar más información sobre este tema.

En tu caso, tienes que agregarle `margin: 0` al `body`.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background-color: #19223e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

/*Main Principal*/

.crear{
    display: flex;

}

/*Paquete Basico*/
.basico{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*Paquete Estandar*/

.estandar{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*Paquete Premiun*/
.premium{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inscripcion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!--Cuerpo pricipal-->
    <main class="crear">
        
        <!--Paquete Básico-->
        <section class="basico">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>BASIC</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">100GB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $1,7/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>
            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>100 GB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Paquete Estandar-->
        <section class="estandar">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>STANDARD</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">200GB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $2,9/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>

            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>200 GB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Paquete Premiun-->
        <section class="premium">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>PREMIUM</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">2TB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $8,9/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>

            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>2 TB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente hay un problema con la altura que estás usando en el `body`. Probé ajustando un poco la altura y la barra de desplazamiento desaparece.

```
html, body{
    height: 95%;
}
```

Revisa el snippet en pantalla completa.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

html, body{
    height: 95%;
}

body{
    background-color: #19223e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

/*Main Principal*/

.crear{
    display: flex;

}

/*Paquete Basico*/
.basico{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*Paquete Estandar*/

.estandar{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*Paquete Premiun*/
.premium{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#212c4d;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inscripcion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!--Cuerpo pricipal-->
    <main class="crear">
        
        <!--Paquete Básico-->
        <section class="basico">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>BASIC</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">100GB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $1,7/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>
            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>100 GB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Paquete Estandar-->
        <section class="estandar">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>STANDARD</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">200GB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $2,9/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>

            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>200 GB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Paquete Premiun-->
        <section class="premium">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <h1>PREMIUM</h1>
                <p class="capacidad">2TB</p>
                <p class="periodo">1 month, then $8,9/month</p>
                <a href="#">Purchase</a>
            </div>

            <div class="opciones">
                <ul>
                    <li>2 TB storage</li>
                    <li>Option to add members</li>
                    <li>Extra member benefits</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

    </main>

</body>
</html>
```